# Django smart selects

Tags: django, chain

I try to chain material and categorie with django smart select but it does not work

What is wrong in my code ?

```
class Demande_Expertise(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    material = models.ForeignKey("Material")
    categorie =  ChainedForeignKey("material.Category",
                          chained_field="material",
                          chained_model_field="name",
                          show_all=False,
                          auto_choose=True)                         
    droits_acces = models.CharField(_('val_champ'), max_length=150, choices = DROITS)
    groupe = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank = True, null= True, default = None)
    etat = models.CharField(_('val_champ'), max_length=150, choices = ETAT, default = '2')

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    category = ChainedForeignKey(Category, verbose_name=_('category'),
                          chained_field="name",
                          chained_model_field="name",
                          show_all=False,
                          auto_choose=True)
    created = models.DateField(_("creation date"), auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Django Clever Selects

https://github.com/PragmaticMates/django-clever-selects

I use it in my Django 1.6 project

Comment: Can you share how to use this app `django-clever-selects` please?

Comment: And apply to django admin too?

Comment: I've use it for user frontend forms

Comment: `django-clever-selects` don't require work with models in Django really? Your functionality is based in ajax and js  really? This can help in the sense of not perform queries or transactions to the database with apps that apply the chaining models really?

Comment: I think you could try it, it's easy

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is incorrect I am giving you an example that works

```
    class Continent(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Country(models.Model):
        continent= models.ForeignKey(Continent)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class City(models.Model):
        continent= models.ForeignKey(Continent)
        country= ChainedForeignKey(Country, chained_field="continent",  chained_model_field="continent", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name

    class Neighborhood(models.Model):
        continent= models.ForeignKey(Continent)
        country= ChainedForeignKey(Country, chained_field="continent",  chained_model_field="continent", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        city= ChainedForeignKey(City, chained_field="country",  chained_model_field="country", show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```